# É recomendado usar return solto em um arquivo PHP? Quando?

Tags: php

É boa prática dar um return em um arquivo PHP simples exemplo:

```
<?php

$config['teste'] = 123;

return $config;
```

Vou explicar melhor tenho esse arquivo di/dependencias.php:

```
<?php


$container['daoExemplo'] = function ($c)
{
    return new ExemploDAO();
};

return $container;
```

Preciso adicionar todas as funções anonimas contidas nesse arquivo em um método, no caso ele percorrerá todo o diretório di/ exemplo:

```
public function requireAllDependencies($directory)
{
    try {
        //setando o diretorio e o tipo de arquivo a ser carregado
        $dir = "{$directory}/*.php";

        //Percorrendo o diretorio e pegado o caminho dos aquivo
        foreach (glob($dir) as $filename)
        {
            //Adicionando as dependencias
            $dependencies = require $filename;
            $this->add($dependencies);
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Erro ao tentar adicionar o arquivo: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Nesse exemplo faria sentido ?

Comment: Faz sentido isso?

Comment: Qual o objectivo?

Comment: @rray Incrivelmente, em certos casos faz.

Comment: Adicionei mais algumas explicações, espero que faça mais sentido.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Em certos casos isso faz sentido. Esqueça essa questão de boa prática, não use se não souber exatamente o que está fazendo.

O [manual do php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.return.php) explica bem como funciona o `return` quando usado fora de funções, seja no arquivo principal ou em includes (são comportamentos diferentes):

> **Se chamada no escopo global**, a execução do script corrente é finalizada.
>
> **Se o arquivo de script corrente for incluído ou requerido** com as funções `include` ou `require`, o controle é passado de volta ao script que está chamando. Além disso, se o script corrente foi incluído com a função `include`, o valor informado ao `return` será retornado como o valor da chamada de `include`.

Segundo essas informações, o seu exemplo de uso é válido sim.

Comment: +1 pelo "Esqueça essa questão de boa prática, não use se não souber exatamente o que está fazendo." eu acho a parte mais importante da resposta :P Acho que vou usar essa frase nas minhas respostas :D :D :D O resto está certo e bom tb :)

Comment: Pode usar à vontade, @Maniero :D

Comment: A citar, no PHP isso é utilizado para facilitar a manutenção do código e, porque não, aumentar a legibilidade do mesmo. Fica muito mais fácil entender, por exemplo, o que é uma variável `$config` quando essa recebe o *return* do `include` do que ter essa variável *magicamente* incluída no escopo. Além de que é possível resolver conflitos de nomes no escopo com essa prática - quando no arquivo incluído é retornado direto o valor e não uma variável, por exemplo.

Comment: Também acho, @AndersonCarlosWoss. Estava pensando em acrescentar seu comentário à resposta, mas como a pergunta fala de boas práticas, receio incentivar gente pouco atenta a sair botando `return;`  em tudo quanto é arquivo.