# Por que o return "finaliza" o script mesmo que dentro uma condição?

Tags: php

### Cenário exemplo

**Exemplo 1**

```
$var = 'A';

function testar($v)
{
    echo 'Início';    
    
    if ($v == 'A') {
    
        echo ' : true';
        return true;
        
    } else {
        
        echo ' : false';
        return false;
    }
    
    echo ' : Fim';
}

testar($var);
```

Saída: `Início : true`

**Exemplo 2**

```
$var = 'A';

function testar($v)
{
    echo 'Início';    
    
    if ($v == 'A') {
    
        echo ' : true';
        
    } else {
        
        echo ' : false';    
    }
    
    echo ' : Fim';
}

testar($var);
```

Saída: `Início : true : Fim`

---

### Dúvida

- Por que o `return` "elimina" o restante do *script*, já que não está contido no `if`?

Comment: Porque quando você usa um return ele retorna o resultado da função.

Comment: Quando você utiliza o return é para indicar que aquele é o resultado esperado da função, então encontrando esta resultado, ele vai retorna o valor da função e finalizar a função.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115335/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/331155/101

Comment: Relacionada => [É recomendado usar return solto em um arquivo PHP? Quando?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/269539/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque quando você da return, você literalmente está saindo da função. Melhor dizendo, você está "retornando" para a função que chamou ela.
Quando a função retorna algo, faz mais sentido. Imagine a seguinte função:

```
int soma(int a, int b)
{
    if (a < 0 || b < 0)
        return 0;

    return a + b;
}
```

Esta função somente soma valores positivos, por exemplo. Então, temos o primeiro `if` que checa se os valores são negativos. Se algum deles for, retornamos como 0. Se temos algo fora das regras da função, porque continuar sua execução? Esse `return 0` indica que iremos retornar para a função que chamou `soma()` o valor de 0. E quando isso acontece, é porque o restante da função não é importante para este caso.

**Resumidamente:** você retornou um resultado e não precisa do restante das ações da função. Notar isto em funções void pode ser `realmente` um pouco mais difícil.

Answer (score 2):

Como utilizou os condicionais if e else, todas as possibilidades são englobadas, então com certeza cairá no em um dos dois, assim, o return será acionado, este para a execução da função, como pode ser visto [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp).

Comment: Sua resposta está correta e boa, diz sobre o ocorrido. Se você detalhar ela mais ainda poderá ficar muito boa.

Comment: Perdão pela ignorância, mas, como esta poderia ficar mais detalhada?